# Не получается добавить время в название

Tags: python

```
if os.path.isfile(file_path) == True:
    old_time = (datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(file_path)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    os.rename(f"Tasks/{user['username']}.txt", f"Tasks/old_{user['username']}_{old_time}.txt")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если файл для пользователя уже существует, то существующий файл переименовать, добавив в него время составления этого старого отчёта в формате "old_Antonette_2020-09-23T15:25.txt"

Таким образом, актуальный отчёт всегда будет без даты в названии. Старые отчёты не удаляются, а переименовываются

Вот тестовое задание дали, проблема в том что при попытке переименовывания файла со старым временем создания вылазит ошибка параметра, если {old_time} не вписывать в .rename , все работает, так же если пытаться вывести на экран old_time тоже все работает

Comment: Вам пишут о том, что в Windows нельзя использовать двоеточие в названии файла

Answer (score 0):

Используйте формат '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S' или что-то в таком ключе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]